# Java equivalent of setInterval in javascript

Tags: java, timing

Basically I want a function to be called every say, 10 milliseconds.

How can I achieve that in Java?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Timer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)).

Comment: It's ok, it does what I want.

Answer (score 10):

Check out java.util.Timer

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a ScheduleExecutorService.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you would create a thread and in the thread loop add a System.sleep(10) to make the thread "sleep" for 10 ms before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Using ExecutorService

```
    ScheduledExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    es.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> System.out.println("Hello World! from ScheduledExecutorService"), 10000, 10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    //es.shutdown();
```

Or by using Timer

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hello World! from Timer");
        }
    }, 10000, 10000);
    //timer.cancel();
```

Cheers!