# Why is this setInterval method undefined?

Tags: java, android, random, fade, volume

I'm trying to randomly change the volume of the media player (mp) every 2 seconds:

```
while (mp.isPlaying()) {
        float x = (float) Math.random();
        float y = (float) Math.random();
        setInterval((mp.setVolume(x,y)),2000);}
```

"The method setInterval is undefined for the type MainActivity"

How do I solve this???

Comment: What is that method? Is it one you created? If so, please show it

Comment: Have you defined the method?

Comment: "_How do I solve this?_" Define the setInterval() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of a while loop is causing the problem. It is looping and not allowing other tasks to  be handled. Refactor your code without the while loop.

Create a function that holds the two random calls and the set volume call and call that with setInterval. Then if that works go back to the function and add your `mp.isPlaying` condition in an if statement that wraps the other three statements. Then read up on clearing a setInterval.

Alternatively take a look at: [Java equivalent of setInterval in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652389/java-equivelant-of-setinterval-in-javascript) if you haven't implemented `setInterval`.